# Broken packages on 16.10 yakkety trying to install libsdl2-dev

Tags: upgrade, package-management, dependencies, sdl

When trying to install `libsdl2-dev` I'm getting this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I upgraded a fresh install from xenial and have ran into these.

I've done the usual, `apt-get dist-upgrade`, clean but no luck. When I start adding the additional packages mentioned it just seems to be going down a rabbit hole of eternally adding extra packages to install.

Below is the output of 
`cd /etc/apt&&find -name \*list -exec egrep -vH "^#|^$" {} \;`
As requested, I've had to modifiy by removing the `http://` from the output as not allowed more than 2 links.

```
./sources.list:deb gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main restricted
./sources.list:deb-src gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties
./sources.list:deb gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main restricted
./sources.list:deb-src gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties
./sources.list:deb gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety universe
./sources.list:deb gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates universe
./sources.list:deb gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety multiverse
./sources.list:deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-updates multiverse
./sources.list:deb gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse
./sources.list:deb-src gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ yakkety-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
./sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main restricted
./sources.list:deb-src security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security main multiverse restricted universe #Added by software-properties
./sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security universe
./sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security multiverse
./sources.list.d/spotify.list:deb repository.spotify.com stable non-free
./sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-yakkety.list:deb ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main
./sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-yakkety.list:deb-src ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main
```

Comment: Try updating your repositories with: `suto apt update`, then run the `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried that and no luck unfortunately. Thanks

Comment: Will you add the output of `cd /etc/apt&&find -name \*list -exec egrep -vH "^#|^$" {} \;` to your question?

Comment: You're welcome.  It's not clear to me what you had to modify.  Is the output you put the exact output without changes to the actual output?  If you made modifications to your actual repository you will have to run the previous commands given to update your repository.  If your output was showing two `http://` in it, it would have been important for me to actually see the output the way it showed from the command, to properly diagnose and understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, as I am new user I'm not allowed to po st more than 2 links,  I had removed the http:// from http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/, leaving just gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/  I hope thats clearer? No manual modifications to my sources.list.  Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: You're welcome... thanks for the clarification.  When you ran the `update` and `upgrade` did you get any errors at all?

Comment: No issues at all when I update/upgrade, it completes normally. I've tried doing autoremove incase of anything leftover, I've also tried apt-get -f install but all completes as expected.

Comment: Run these commands: (1) `apt-get clean` (2) `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (3) `sudo apt-get -f install` (4) `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I've ran all of those commands and unfortunately it hasn't worked.

Comment: Will you place the output of this command into a file and put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and place a pastebin link here. `cat /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I put it at filebin.com as it was too large for pastebin, http://filebin.ca/3Dq0kmmRl3nH/output

Comment: 'Held broken packages' usually means a *version conflict*, usually caused by software from non-Ubuntu sources...like your graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-yakkety.list. Disable that source, uninstall all the PPA-provided software, and use the packages from the compatible, tested, trusted Ubuntu repos instead.

Comment: I know it was large, but didn't know it was that large.

Comment: Run this command.  `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libsdl2-dev`

Comment: That sorted it! Thanks, after that I managed to install! Thanks for all of your help here!

Comment: @admg Thanks for the update and acknowledgment of the steps that works.  I organized the steps provided in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First clean and update your repositories with:**

```
$ apt-get clean
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**Then cleanly remove the problem app.**

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge libsdl2-dev
```

After purging the app reinstall it normally.  If this fails perform a more forceful removing:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libsdl2-dev
```

After having should sufficient clean the conflicts and allow it to be properly installed.